# Access to variables from outside function

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, but a bit more experienced in C++, which is why the below code example puzzles me a bit.

```
def foo():
    y = x
    print y

x = 5
foo()
```

Running this code prints the value 5. How can the value of variable x be known inside foo()?
The above code would not run in C++, it would if we had done:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 5;
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Because here x is a variable in the global scope which is declared (and defined) prior to foo().
Is it working in Python because x gets added to the global symbol table?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your analysis sounds right. You can try printing the output of `globals()` from the function to see for yourself.

Comment: You should take a look at this too: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: @juanchopanza It was correct. The dictionary obtained from the globals() function contained 'x': 5.

Answer (score 4):

Everything at global scope is visible from inside functions for reading. That's how it must be: there is no distinction in Python between names that point to variables and names that point to functions, so if this didn't work you wouldn't even be able to call functions.

But if you wanted to modify x, you'd need the global keyword.

As to why it works when the variable is defined after the function: Python doesn't attempt to resolve references at compile time, it does when the function is called: because everything in python is dynamic, there's no way of telling ahead of time if a variable is defined.

Comment: "But that if you wanted to modify x, you'd need the global keyword." Thanks, very useful to know!

Answer (score 3):

The real distinction is how variable lookup works in the two languages.

In C++, code is compiled in one pass. When the compiler reads the code for `foo`, it sees `x`, and doesn't know what to make of this *identifier* yet. It could be a variable of *any* type, or it could be a function, or it could be a typographical error. If it hasn't already seen a definition for `x` - something that explains *what kind of thing* x is, although not necessarily its actual *value* - then it will report an error immediately.

When Python sees the `x`, it knows that's a *name* - i.e., an identifier - because it matches the appropriate token type, and isn't a language keyword. In Python, *everything is an object and we really mean that* - that includes functions. There is no type checking at compile time, so we don't care whether `x` is an integer, or a function, or just what - all of these things can be handled the same way. (Yes, you can print functions - but it doesn't show you anything useful, like the original code; it just gives you a stub with some basic information about the type, name and object ID). There really can't be any type checking, because Python's variables don't have a type (not even an implicit one, like in type-inferred languages like Haskell) - Python's **values** have a type.

There also isn't a validity check to see if `x` actually exists, because again there can't be one - there are ways in Python to create names dynamically (please don't, generally speaking).

However, enough analysis can be done at compile time to determine that `x` isn't a local variable, so Python produces code that says "look for a global variable named `x` and use that". Any resulting errors occur *when `foo` actually runs*, in the form of *exceptions*. If `x` doesn't actually exist as a global, it will raise `NameError`; if it exists but the corresponding object is the wrong type (normally impossible for `print`, but possible e.g. for `+`), it raises `TypeError`, and if it's the right type but an invalid value, it will generally raise either `ValueError` or a subtype of that (e.g., an invalid numeric index into a `list` will raise `IndexError`, which is a subtype of `ValueError`).

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find this code useful.

```
def foo():
    y = x # y becames local while x ..is found as a global
    print "globals=", globals()
    print "locals=", locals()
    print y

x = 5 # here you declare variable x with global scope and with value 5
foo()

--------------------
$ python test.py
globals= {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, 'x': 5, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <function foo at 0x7f0d4cbf05f0>, '__doc__': None}
locals= {'y': 5}
5
```

Comment: I did basically the same test, and got the same result as you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Python (just like Lua) treats global variables as if they had always existed once you define them. Thus, after defining the function and setting x to 5, both of them exist and have always existed for Python. When calling `foo()` it will search the global and local namespace for a variable named 'x' and it will find one with the value 5, and print it.